# Update dynamically headers of DataTable in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, datatable

Is there an efficient way of updating dynamically the headers of a `Table` after performing `T = array2table(P)` on a matrix `P` of dimension `e.g.(1x120)` rather than manually resorting to `T.Properties.VariableNames{i} = xxx` for I belonging to `[2;120]`?

As `Matlab` assigns by default `{Var1,....Var120}` on `T`, the idea is to iterate over each column header of `T` and assign then a new name `= T_Var2,....T_Var120}` where T represents the `table name`

Once unique column headers is performed on `T`, then `outerjoin` could be used with other tables (using the expected solution) as they will share a unique key on `Var1`. A feedback would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the headers when you call `array2table`.

Here I first create all of the names (use your desired table name in place of `'Table_Var'` and then assign when creating the table.

```
% Create unique headers, 'Table_Var1', 'Table_Var2', 'Table_Var3', ...
headers = arrayfun( @(x) sprintf('Table_Var%d',x), 1:size(P,2), 'uni', 0 );
% Assign headers when creating the table
T = array2table( P, 'VariableNames', headers );
```

If you wanted column 1 to always have the same name, say `'Col1'`, and only columns `2:end` to use the table name, you could use:

```
headers = ['Col1', arrayfun( @(x) sprintf('Table_Var%d',x), 2:size(P,2), 'uni', 0 ) ]
```

Once you have a cell array of headers, you can also just rename the table variable names in one shot (you don't need to do this if you did it at the `array2table` stage)

```
T.Properties.VariableNames = headers;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Little point: `headers = {'Col1', arrayfun( @(x) sprintf('Table_Var%d',x), 2:size(P,2), 'uni', 0 ) };` does not produce the desired outcome, thus I've used your first suggestion then updated the first column using `T.Properties.VariableNames{1} = xxxx`. Thanks again.

Comment: @dark When you say it doesn't produce the desired outcome, what do you mean? It should be trivial for us to make it work like you want! I just edited it, think I might have needed a bracket change.

Comment: I do confirm that your latest update fixes the issue targeting  `headers(2:size(P,2))`. Before the update `headers{1,1}` was fine, however  `headers{2,2}` created somehow another cell array with values starting from `Table_Var1...Table_Var2` till end. Thank you.